# Can you overlay clickable shapes over a google map for display on website

Tags: google-maps

I want to have a google map on my website overlaid with rectangular shapes that can then be clicked onto to open a link. The rectangular shapes relate to buildings, so a larger building would be overlaid with a larger shape.

Clearly the shapes relate to an area of the map so would reduce in size as you zoomed out, and increase as you zoom in.

Is this possible with a google api, Can I do this ?

Comment: Why close, its a programming question

Comment: What have you tried?
The answer to your question is read the documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes

Comment: That could be the answert to many questions on SO, there are so many google apis I couldnt make sense of it I was looking at Google Maps Embed API and Places API. Maybe shapes would work but that would require alot of client javascript to be run every time, I was expecting that I could modify the map at server end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make clickable shapes with the GoogleMaps API,

You have to define the latitude and longitude points of the shape in an array, like the following:

```
var StackExchangeNYLatLon = [
    {lat: 40.708788, lon: -74.006676},
    {lat: 40.708808, lon: -74.006822},
    {lat: 40.709009, lon: -74.006582},
    {lat: 40.708963, lon: -74.006515}
];
```

Make a `div` element for the map to populate,

Then define the `map` (with the `div` id and options as parameters into `new google.maps.Map`):

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('your-div-id'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 40.709009, lon: -74.006582}, //This is the one of the provided above
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
```

Then, construct the polygon and set the `map`:

```
var StackExchangeNYHeadquarters = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: StackExchangeNYLatLon,
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});
StackExchangeNYHeadquarters.setMap(map);
```

If you wanted a marker you could do the following code instead:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: options.latLonData,
    map: map,
    title: 'My House'
});
```

Now, add an `eventListener` to the polygon:
This is the part where you define what happens when you click the shape,
You could make it directly open the link, or open a nice little dialog box with content you can fill.

If you wanted to open a link you could have `document.location.href`, whereas if you wanted content, you'd need to append a `contentString` to the `infoWindow`.

```
StackExchangeNYHeadquarters.addListener('click', function(event){
    document.location.href = 'http://example.com/mylink/';
});
```

and now, make the `infoWindow`:

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

All of the above code should be wrapped in a `callback` handler that is passed along as a query string in the API call:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=startMap"></script>
```

---

So the above code should look like:

```
function startMap(options){
    var latLonData = options.latLonData;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('your-div-id'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: options.center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: StackExchangeNYLatLon,
        strokeColor: 'blue',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
    polygon.addListener('click', , function(event){
        document.location.href = 'http://example.com/mylink/';
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}
function StackExchangeHeadquartersBuild(){
    options = {
        latlonData: [
            {lat: 40.708788, lon: -74.006676},
            {lat: 40.708808, lon: -74.006822},
            {lat: 40.709009, lon: -74.006582},
            {lat: 40.708963, lon: -74.006515}
        ],
        center: {lat: 40.709009, lon: -74.006582}
    };
    startMap(options);
}
```

You could attach the callback to a factory, so that a lot of elements can be created at once without 500 individual functions for each location.

Comment: Thankyou, so my main query is I have a map with lots of these clickable shapes (say 200) instead of 200 markers would that be practical performance wise or would it be problematic

Comment: It may be problematic, I don't know, it really depends on how Google's library would handle them.

Comment: There may be workarounds, for example if you were displaying every listing on the page in one map, you could just reduce the amount of listings to a page.

Comment: Let me ask slightly differently, the code above uses the javascriptAPi right, if I was just addig markers instead of shapes would that also be done at javascript level or would that be done in a different way ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor see my latest update for code relating to markers

Comment: thanks, but what I meant was is do we have to use Javascript because we a reusing shapes or we have to use Javascript even if we were using markers. if we didmarkers as you describe I guess the performance difference between using shapes and markers wouldnt be so much. But if the usual way to do markers was different there might be a big performance difference.

Comment: The performance would be better with markers than polygons, but either one would have performance issues at 200~ on a page at once, you would want to use JavaScript to make all the shapes/

Comment: 'you would want to use JavaScript to make all the shapes', do you mean you wouldnt want ?

Comment: No, I mean you should use JavaScript to make all the shapes.

Comment: Im still unclear, if I was doing markers instead of shapes would I also have to use javascript to do the markers or is there an alternative way ?

Comment: If you were doing markers, it would be better to use JavaScript.